# For each record in a table, insert a record in another table and put the key into the first table's record

Tags: mysql

I am localizing an application and need to convert existing TEXT columns to have multiple translated versions of the text.

The original table looks like this:

### person

- personId: INT
- description: VARCHAR(20)
- (other columns)

To store the localized text, I created a new table:

### text

- textId: INT (auto-incrementing)
- languageId: INT
- text: TEXT

I want to replace the person.description column with a new person.descTextId column.

For each person that has a value in the description column but descTextId is null:

1. Insert a new text record with that person's description (English
   languageId=1)
2. Update the person's descTextId to the new textId
   value

Then remove the person.description column.

What is the cleanest way to do all of this?  Do I need to create a procedure and cursor or is there a clever MySQL syntax that would help with this? How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a temporary procedure and loop.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS moveToTextTable;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE moveToTextTable()
BEGIN
  DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE id INT DEFAULT 0;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM person WHERE description IS NOT NULL AND description <> '';
  WHILE i<n DO
    SELECT personId INTO id FROM person WHERE description IS NOT NULL AND description <> '' AND descTextId IS NULL LIMIT 1;
    INSERT INTO text (languageId, text) SELECT 1, description FROM person WHERE personId = id;
    UPDATE person SET descTextId = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE personId = id;
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
;;

DELIMITER ;
CALL moveToTextTable();
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS moveToTextTable;
```